# configure content type "application/xml" at service end

Tags: c#, xml, rest, wcf, wcf-rest

I have created a basic WCF REST web service in C#, and I need it to accept a content type of "application/xml" in an HTTP POST. The code I have will only work if the content type of the POST is "application/x-www-form-urlencode", and when I try to make the POST data content type of "application/xml", I get a 400 error message.

The WCF web service is using a behaviorConfiguration of "RestBehavior" and a binding of "webHttpBinding".

The client code that is composing and sending the post is like the following:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(GetURL());
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
response.Close();
```

When I change the content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" it works, but this client code  with "application/xml" here gets a 400 error from the web service. I need this to work with content type of "application/xml".

Below is the XML that I am trying to post with both the Content types.

```
<tma>  <tma_header>    <sourcecountry>India</sourcecountry>    <sourcecompany>ABC</sourcecompany>    <sourcesystem>ZYX</sourcesystem>  </tma_header>  <tma_body>    <empcareerdetails>      <state>Something</state> <lastname>lname</lastname>      <firstname>fname</firstname>      <ipaddress>0.0.0.0</ipaddress>      <totalworkexp>20</totalworkexp>      <departmentappliedfor>IT Production Support</departmentappliedfor>      <city>zzz</city>      <pincode>123123</pincode>      <currentemployer>MS</currentemployer>      <qualification>ss< qualification>      <address>somewhere</address>      <email>abc@x.co</email>      <dob>dd/mm/yyyy</dob>      <currentindustry>Internet/Dot com/ISP</currentindustry>      <gender>false</gender>      <campaignid>123456</campaignid>      <phoneno/>      <uploadedresume>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</uploadedresume>      <mobile>1231231321</mobile>    </empcareerdetails>  </tma_body></tma>
```

I am thinking it is something simple, Please Help!

Comment: do you also change actual POST content to xml format?

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes..Thats xml..

Comment: it is strange, because 400 means **BadRequest** (syntax error), like if you tell service that this is _"application/xml"_ but body of request contains a JSON string (or invalid XML). If the service really could not handle XML, it would respond 422. Can you please show us what is in `byteArray` variable (as text)?

Comment: but the same variable, I can post using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and things are working fine with it. Which means byteArray or xml I am posting is valid.

Comment: Can you get the xml using a browswer?  You may be able to get the xml without a request uswing xml linq : XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL).

Comment: _"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"_ **!=** _"application/xml"_. If you sending exactly same `byteArray` with different `ContentType` - it will not work. Can you please show us what is in `byteArray` variable (as text) when you sending _"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"_, and when you sending _"application/xml"_?

Comment: I have update the question with the xml that I am trying to Post.

Comment: Can you please show us what is in `byteArray` variable (as text) when you sending "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", and when you sending "application/xml"?

Comment: xml that you posted is not valid, btw